# how to Add JavaScript in HTML In Java

Tags: java, javascript, android

```
function linkClick(e) {
  alert(e.target.href);
}

function setDefaultLinkHandlers(){
  links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
  links[i].addEventListener('click', linkClick, false);
}

document.onload=setDefaultLinkHandlers();
```

This is JavaScript

```
String Url = "http://dev.taxmann.com/actruleservice/ActRuleService.asmx/GetFileHTML?FileID_or_FullPath=102120000000025184";
String htmlResp = getStringPage(Url);

WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();

String k = Html.fromHtml((String) htmlResp).toString().replace(");'", "");
```

Here `k` is String where am getting HTML, I have to add that JavaScript in this HTML. Can anyone tell me how I will add this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String myJavascript = "<script>"+"your javascript here"+"</script></head>";

htmlResp = htmlResp.replace("</head>", myJavascript);

String k = ....
```

Comment: String myJavascript = "<script>"+"function linkClick(e) { alert(e.target.href);}function setDefaultLinkHandlers(){  links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++)  links[i].addEventListener('click', linkClick, false);  }  document.onload=setDefaultLinkHandlers();"+"</script></head>";  It Should Like this Arjun